# Force due to ring of charge

Tags: electrostatics, vectors, calculus

I am currently taking Physics II and have recently been focused on this problem: Suppose there is a ring of uniform linear charge density $\:\lambda\:$ and radius R and a point P at a height $\: z_{_\mathrm P}=h\:$ **vertically upwards the center of the ring**. What is the magnitude $\:\mathrm E\:$ of the force $\:\mathbf E\:$ that P experiences? My professor, and all other sources that I could find online, solve this problem by noticing that the $\:x\:$ and $\:y\:$ components of $\:\mathbf E\:$ will cancel out due to the symmetries of the ring, so we need only calculate the force in the $\:z\:$ direction, which is simply $\:\mathrm E\cos\theta\:$, where $\:\theta\:$ is the angle between the $\:z$-axis and the line made between a point on the ring and P. However, while I fully understand both that Ecos(theta) is the z-component of E and that the x and y components will cancel out, and I do believe that Ecos(theta) is the correct answer, I take issue with what I find to be a contradiction in the math, or at the vary least an error in the reasoning used. Namely, if the x and y components cancel out due to symmetry then the magnitude of the z component should seemingly be equal to the total magnitude of E. However, as I mentioned, all of the sources I've found use the fact that the symmetries cancel as a justification for finding the z-component; if the z-component is equal to E, then why can't we just calculate E to find the answer instead of specifically looking for the z-component of E? Another phrasing of my confusion which might make for a clearer question: if Ecos(theta) "represents" the magnitude of E in the z-direction, then what does E itself "represent" if is not equivalent to Ecos(theta) but it lacks any components in the x and y directions due to symmetry?

Comment: If you find this confusing, why not just calculate $E_x$, $E_y$, and $E_z$?

Comment: The x,y components of the field are zero, only the z component is non-trivial. The electric field is the vector $(0,0,E_z)$.

Comment: There are two $E$ being conflated here. There is the electric field at that point, which, as you correctly noted, is purely along the z direction and thus the full field is exactly equal to the electric field's z component. However, the computation being made is to sum the electric field due to each little ring element, and that field is not purely in the z direction. It is only that the symmetry of the ring guarantees that all the x-y components will later cancel away. So to compute the correct behaviour, we have to sum the z components alone.

Comment: Duplicate : [Electric field above a ring of charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/658668/electric-field-above-a-ring-of-chargee).

Comment: $|\vec{a}+\vec{b}| \ne |\vec{a}| + |\vec{b}|$, in general.